# Issues with File Parsing in Azure OpenAI Assistant

Tags: openai-api, azure-openai

I'm currently integrating Azure OpenAI Assistant into a project and facing difficulties with parsing uploaded files in the playground. Despite trying multiple formats such as `.txt`, `.pdf`, and `.md`, I consistently encounter parsing errors when the Assistant tries to read the files, both when running my code and directly through the Azure playground UI.

**Error Description:**

After uploading the files and initiating the process, the playground returns a full-stack trace indicating a parsing failure. Subsequently, the Assistant provides a response that seems to be a mix of hallucinations, containing little to no context related to the uploaded document.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- Checked the integrity and format of the uploaded documents.
- Attempted the process with different file formats.
- Ensured the documents are text-based and not image-based PDFs.
- Ran the same setup using OpenAI's standard API where it executed as expected.

**Observations:**

- The files appear to upload correctly.
- The error triggers a stack trace in the playground.
- Similar setups work correctly in OpenAI's non-Azure environment.

**Additional Context:**

- Azure OpenAI Assistant is in a beta release.
- I am attempting to process the files for a simple document retrieval and Q&A task.
  Below is an example of the stack trace received (error details and traceback):

[image]